# How to make a NSMutableDictionary out of a NSCFDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, nsmutabledictionary

I need to `removeAllObjects` from a `NSMutableDictionary`. The NSMutableDictionary is populated through a JSON response. In some cases I get a `NSCFDictionary` as result. I tried to do a `mutableCopy` to an NSMutableDictionary, but the Dictionary stays a NSCFDictionary...

**How do I solve my problem and get an NSMutableDictionary out of a NSCFDitionary?**

#### Take the JSON and store it

```c
-(void)putImageDetails:(NSMutableDictionary *)json {
    NSMutableDictionary *tmp = [json mutableCopy]; // __NSCFDictionary removeAllObjects]: mutating method sent to immutable object'
    self.imageDetails = tmp;
}
```

#### removeAllObjects and populate them new

```c
-(void)didLoadImageDetails {

    [self.detailData removeAllObjects];   // This does not work, as it's still a NSCFDict

    NSString *ssource = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"do%@", self.socialSource];        
    SEL functionCall = NSSelectorFromString(ssource);
    [self performSelector:functionCall];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

### Here the debug output

#### Normal working case with NSMutableDictionary

[image: Normal working case with NSMutableDictionary]

#### Try to Tansform a NSCFDictonary to NSMutableDictionary but it does not work

the variable **json and tmp are still NSCFDictonary**. tmp should in my understanding be a NSMutableDitionary... (see variable view)

[image: Try to Tansform a NSCFDictonary to NSMutableDictionary but it does not work]

#### This will lead to the error: __NSCFDictionary removeAllObjects: mutating method sent to immutable object

[image: Still an NSCFDictionary]

Comment: Show the code where you receive and deserialise the JSON.

Comment: You're making a NSMutableCopy to `imageDetails` but call `removeAllObjects` on detailData ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `NSJSONSerialization +JSONObjectWithData:options:error:` to get the dictionary from your JSON data. It takes an `options` parameter which you should be setting to `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` so that the created arrays and dictionaries from the JSON are all mutable.

Your current code is making `self.imageDetails` a mutable dictionary (though none of its contents are likely to be mutable), but then you are trying to mutate `self.detailData`. It isn't clear how these 2 are related but you should set up the mutability of the data structures when created (deserialised from the JSON).

Comment: Did this (*but you should set up the mutability of the data structures when created*), was a problem of the content, which I could solve with Surfers and Wains solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have the add the `NSCFDictonary` objects not to assign the `NSCFDictonary` to `NSMutableDictionary` So do like following,

```
NSData *data =[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError * error=nil;
NSDictionary *responseJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:responseJSON];
```

Comment: You are creating 2 dictionaries here, both mutable. You don't need `mutableCopy` and `dictionaryWithDictionary:`.